# How can I adjust my screen's color temperature?

Tags: settings, screen

[Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) is a Linux application similar to Windows' [F.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/), which gives the screen a red tinge automatically at night. Supposedly, it reduces eye strain and helps prevent sleep problems.

Is there any way I can adjust my screen's color temperature to create the same effect on Android?

Comment: I use F.lux for Windows and Mac, I love it. It's funny that you asked this, just last night I was wondering if F.lux existed for Android...

Comment: Very similar question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5830/automatic-adjust-brightness-through-out-the-day

Comment: As a sidenote, here's a question about the *claims* of F.lux and Redshift at Skeptics StackExchange: ["Does the color temperature of a computer screen affect sleep patterns?"](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3465)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a fair few [blue light filter apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=blue%20light%20filter&c=apps) on the Play Store that may suit your needs. The exact features will vary, but they all fit the general scheme of allowing you to adjust the color temperature of your screen.

Additionally, if your device is rooted, you can actually use [f.lux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.justgetflux.flux) nowadays.

Comment: Your link is broken, and I am not able find another. Is there something similar?

Comment: Looks like it was de-listed. I'm not aware of anywhere else that hosted a copy, so I re-wrote this to point to other apps on the Play Store. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

Well I know for a fact that there is Cyanogenmod ROM which has "filter options" one of them being only turn on red, I know its not automatic, but there is widgets for the home screen. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it by app but it would require root access.

Comment: Tasker or Locale could probably turn it on, but I'm guessing a gradual change wouldn't be possible.

Comment: unfotunatly when selected it completely turns off all other colors

Comment: Sorry, but I could not find that setting (CYM11 here). Where's that?

Comment: Settings-> Display & Lights-> (go to the bottom) Color calibration, at least that's what its like on my nexus 5

Answer (score 3):

[NeyetLight](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.absurdsoft.neyetlight) looks like it would do the trick.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Twilight works well, although it's just a screen filter, it's automated and very similar to f.lux if you move the color temp to the right more

I love it although it does look terrible, it's all we have, and I am not going to root my phone just to have a true color temp change that's insane, plus it voids my warranty which I need to have and rooting is insanely difficult, DO NOT tell me it's easy i've read the instructions for it -- it's NOT EASY

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Screen Filter](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.haxor) app.

Comment: Gee whiz, man! Give us a link!

Comment: unfortunately it's a no go but thanks for recommendation

Comment: Is it just the color?  Maybe you could ask the dev to add color selection.

Comment: yeah it's the color , regular LCD color makes your brain think its in sunlight and keeps you awake , more red color suppose to prevent that, i will try reaching the dev thx for the tip

Answer (score 1):

[Screen Adjuster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netmanslab.sa) by Netman that allows you to control the red tint on the phone.

Comment: Your link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

Current builds of CyanogenMod have a feature called LiveDisplay. It's very similar to f.lux, automatic changes in the evening and all. It actually changes the color temperature of the screen; it's not an overlay.

It can be turned on from
`Settings` > `Display & lights` > `LiveDisplay` > `Display mode` > `automatic`.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed an app to adjust the screen temperature. It has no ads, over 200 good reviews, and small file size.

> Bluelight Filter is a tiny utility (just 86kb!) to reduce the harmful
>   effect of blue light emitted by smartphones & tablets. Blue light
>   interferes with the sleep hormone production of our body and affects
>   sleep.

[image: Bluelight Filter]

**https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.panagola.app.bluef**

Affiliation: Developer, Non-profit

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't provide red tint, but for late night, ultra-dim reading I use [adjBrightness](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.deskangel.adjbrightness). It does require a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

## [Twilight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.lux) (free)

Twilight automatically makes the screen redder at night, with options for color temperature, intensity, and brightness. It has a nice Material design too.

## [Lux Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vitocassisi.luxlite) (free) or [Lux Auto Brightness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux) ($3.80)

From Lux Dash > Triple star icon, you can enable/disable Night Mode and change Night Mode's color temperature. Automatic color temperature changing at sunset requires the paid version.

Answer (score 0):

[Red Moon Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerocode.redmoon.lite)  (free) or [Red Moon - Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jmstudios.redmoon) (payed).

[image]