# Automatic adjust brightness through out the day

Tags: sensors, screen-brightness

It does not seem that automatic brightness works well on my Nexus S.

Basically, I want my phone's brightness to adjust throughout the day. Either that, or something that automatically adjusts brightness based on the ambient light sensor.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5816/is-there-an-app-similar-to-redshift-for-android

Comment: @Al I think this is OK, it's different enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [AdvancedBrightness](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jariporola.advancedbrightness)? It's not automatic - you'd have to configure it accordingly. However, since you said "adjust throughout the day," this may well be a suitable app for your needs. Oh, and it's free and very small (33kb).

Comment: Awesome suggestion! I think I'm going with this.

Answer (score 5):

An application like [Locale](http://www.twofortyfouram.com/) ($9.99USD) will let you do that. At say 9 am you can adjust the brightness to one setting, then add another condition to adjust the brightness to a different setting at a different time.

[Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) should be able to do it as well. It does a lot of what Locale does, plus more. It also supports all the Locale plug-ins. It is also about $5.99USD.

Comment: +1 for the Tasker application

Comment: I'll give them a try! Too bad Android's try-out window has been decreased. Would of been nice to have 24 hours to try these out.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind programming it in, [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5rZWJhYi5MbGFtYSJd) is a free alternative to Locale and Tasker! :) It has date/time of day triggers with screen brightness actions (along with quite a few others!).